# The CSS style is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use CSS within the HTMl document but it does not seem to work i tried using it externally as well but it did not work then either. I don't know where its going wrong it should create like a green box 960px wide and 200 px height at the top of the page but its not doing anything

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Xbox UK Home</title>
    <meta name=“description” content=“Xbox is a gaming console created by Microsoft”/>
    <meta name=“keywords” content=“Xbox, games, Microsoft, Xbox Live” />
    <meta name=“robots” content=“nofollow” />

<style>
#header {
width: 960px;
background-color:#006400;
height: 200px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
    <!—-Main Header—->
    <header id=“header”> </header>

    <!—-Second Header—->
    <section> </section>

    <!—-Main Image—->
    <section> </section>

    <!—-Box One —-!>
    <Section> </Section>

    <!—-Box Two —-!>
    <Section> </Section>

    <!—-Box Three —-!>
    <Section> </Section>

    <!—-Box Four —-!>
    <Section> </Section>

    <!—-Box Five —-!>
    <Section> </Section>

    <Footer></Footer>


</body>
```

Comment: It seems quote bug “ ” should be ""

Comment: Using MS Word as a html editor, perhaps? :O

Comment: Remove # from CSS and it would be fine :)

Comment: @Jatin... heh, clever :)

Comment: @Jatin - the OP is presumably using the id "header" as opposed to the tag header for a reason

Comment: I am using textedit because its a mac i could not find anything like notepad++ for mac

Comment: @AlexSmith - Just a word of warning; change the erroneous quotes globally in your document... I can see them in your meta tags too!

Answer (score 8):

You have `<header id=“header”> </header>`

get rid of the microsoft quotes

```
"header"
```

Comment: not only from header but also from meta tags, saying remove those quotes would be nice

Answer (score 0):

It is an error you get with those quotes. use ""
for example:

```
<header id="header"> </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML to:

```
<!—-Main Header—->
 <header> </header>
```

And

```
header {
width: 960px;
background-color:#006400;
height: 200px;
}
```

And everything should work

Answer (score -5):

I believe your style tag needs the type attr. `<style type="text/css">`... I believe you can get away with `<script>` and not the type but with styles you need the type.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with type="" but with the kind of quotes he is using